# Apache process dies unexpectedly

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I'm testing the limit of my Python Flask web application running on an Apache web server by making a request that takes over 30minutes to complete. The request requires thousands of database requests (one after the other) to a MySQL database. I understand this should ideally be run as a separate asynchronous process outside the apache server, but let's ignore that for now. The problem I'm having is that although this runs completely when I test it on my mac, it dies abruptly when running it on a linux server (Amazon linux on AWS EC2). I've not been able to figure out exactly what's killing it. I've checked that the server isn't running out of memory. The process uses very little RAM. I've not been able to find any Apache config parameter or any error message that makes sense to me (even after setting apache logLevel to debug). Please I need help on where to look. Here're more details about my setup:

---

**Run Time**

**Server:** It died after 8mins, 27mins, 21mins & 22mins respectively. Note that most of these runs were on a UAT server and this was the only request the server was processing.

**Mac:** It ran much slower that it runs on the server. The process ran successfully and took 2hours 47mins.

---

**Linux Server details:**
2 virtual CPUs and 4GB RAM

**OS** (output of `uname -a`)
Linux ip-172-31-63-211 3.14.44-32.39.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 11 20:33:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Apache error_log:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XXZfJyzJYsNkFDU3hJekRRUlU/view?usp=sharing

**Apache config file:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XXZfJyzJYsM2lhSmxfVVRNNjQ/view?usp=sharing

**Apache version** (output of `apachectl -V`)

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)  
Server built:   Jul 29 2016 21:42:17  
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61  
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1  
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1  
Architecture:   64-bit  
Server MPM:     prefork  
  threaded:     no  
    forked:     yes (variable process count)  
Server compiled with....  
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP  
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE  
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT  
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256  
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"  
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"  
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"  
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"  
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"  
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

---

**Mac details:**

**Apache config file:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XXZfJyzJYsRUd6NW5NY3lON1U/view?usp=sharing

**Apache version** (output of `apachectl -V`)

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)  
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19  
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52  
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2  
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2  
Architecture:   64-bit  
Server MPM:     prefork  
  threaded:     no  
    forked:     yes (variable process count)  
Server compiled with....  
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP  
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE  
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT  
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256  
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"  
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"  
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"  
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"  
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"  
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: you know it completes in 30 minutes how?  by running it at a command line?

Comment: I know it's meant to take over 30minutes because I can see the fraction of records it's processed out of the total number of records. It's simply meant to do a repetitive task thousands of times.